# Thymeleaf: how to include page specific javascript using layouts?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Using thymeleaf is there a way to decorate my layout w/ my page specific javascript and javascript includes?

```
<!--My Layout -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/header :: header">

</div>
<div class="container">
    <div layout:fragment="content">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!--My Page -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html layout:decorator="layout">
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div layout:fragment="content">
    hello world
</div>

<script src="pageSpecific1.js"></script>
<script src="pageSpecific2.js"></script>
<script>
 alert("hello world")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Move the javascript into the layout? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: Where is your javascript stored? How about the thymeleaf templates?

Answer (score 61):

In your layout template, put a `fragment` for the script.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
    <body>
       ..
       <th:block layout:fragment="script"></th:block>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in your page template, you can then add the script for that page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorator="template.html">
    <body>
       ...
       <th:block layout:fragment="script">
            <script th:src="@{/page.js}"></script>
            <script>
                 function foo() {
                    ...
                 }
            </script>
       </th:block>
    </body>
</html>
```

Don't forget to set the `layout:decorator` in your page template.

Comment: Cool thanks! This works but is there anyway not to wrap this in a div tag?

Comment: Yes, instead of using `<div>` tags, use `<th:block>` tags. This will result in the rendered page, not being wrapped in divs. To me, from a maintenance and development standpoint, the term `block` is much more explicit as a formatting construct that will be removed in the rendered page

Comment: where does the JavaScript file `page.js` need to be for `/page.js` to correctly load? I'm using SpringBoot and have my `.js` file in same folder as thymeleaf template - `/src/main/resources/` -  yet `/page.js` does not find it.

Comment: Spring Boot by default serves from the following locations: `classpath:/META-INF/resources/`, `classpath:/resources/`, `classpath:/static/`, `classpath:/public/`. You can static resources in one of the following location: `src/main/resources/resources`, `src/main/resources/static`, `src/main/resources/public` or the `META-INF/resources` folder. https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot