# Using th:block (fragments) in thymeleaf templates

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm still kind of new to Thymeleaf and SpringBoot.

I have been trying to inject a block with all the javascript mappings into a page - dashboardAdmin.html using thymeleaf fragments.

I have been able to inject fragments with enveloped with a block correctly using the conventional fragments however since i have to inject multiple script tags that are not within any tag in the html template, I wasn't able to use the conventional method.

I found a similar question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215705/thymeleaf-how-to-include-page-specific-javascript-using-layouts) and have follow the specific solution provided but still have not succeeded and I have added the dependency. Perhaps there is some sort of syntax error that I do not know about. 
Since I couldn't find much reference on this, can anyone kindly advice me on this?

This is the *fragment.html* which contains all the templates to be inserted into other pages

```
<body>
<th:block layout:fragment="script">
    <script th:src="@{/vendor/login_v14/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
    <script th:src="@{/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js}"></script>
    <!-- jsGrid -->
    <script th:src="@{/vendor/jsgrid/demos/db.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/vendor/jsgrid/jsgrid.min.js}"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script th:src="@{/js/main.js}"></script>
</th:block>
</body>
```

While this is the page template that I am injecting the block to - *dashboardAdmin.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"
             xmlns:layout="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
             layout:decorate="~{fragments/fragments}">
<head th:replace="fragments/fragments :: head">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">

<!--js scripts-->
<th:block layout:fragment="script">

</th:block>
</body>
```

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here, it will be much appreciated :D !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify your HTML to get what you need.

In your `dashboardAdmin.html`, insert something like this at the location where you want to place your fragment:

```
<div th:replace = "fragment.html :: script1">
</div>
```

(You may need to adjust that `"fragment.html"` if your fragment HTML file is at some other location in your resources directory.)

In your `fragment.html`, you can use something like this:

```
<th:block th:fragment="script1">
    <div>your content here, instead of this div</div>
</th:block>

<th:block th:fragment="script2">
    <div>your content here, instead of this div</div>
</th:block>
```

This is the entire contents of the fragment file, in my case - but obviously you can replace my `<div>...</div>` with all the HTML from your question.

I included 2 separate named fragments in the above example, for illustration.

The contents of the "script1" block (but not the containing block itself) will be inserted into your `dashboardAdmin.html` page.

It should be as simple as that, if I have understood your question correctly. Basically, the approach should be no different from the way you mentioned you have already been able to insert fragments into other HTML files.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried out your suggestion and it works. I just didn't understand how to th:block exactly and the file path was an issue.